# Clear input ng-model when ng-hide is true AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up this `<input>` in a way that when `ng-hide` is true, whatever in `ng-model` is reset.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="account.AccountName" ng-hide="account.AccountStatus == 'Terminated'">
```

So there will be a dropdown list containing `Active` and `Terminated` binded to `ng-model="account.AccountStatus"`. When it's `Active`, the field Account Name would have text there. I want to make it that when I switch to `Terminated`, that input field is hidden and `account.AccountName` is set to "".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [ng-change] attribute and define function in the controller to handle change event and reset AccountName if AccountStatus equals to 'Terminated'.
Example:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="account.AccountName" ng-hide="account.AccountStatus == 'Terminated'">
    <select ng-change="selectChange()" name="selectState" ng-model="account.AccountStatus">
      <option value="Active">Active</option>
      <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      angular.module('examleModule', []).controller('exampleController',['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.account = {
            AccountStatus: 'Active',
            AccountName: ''
         };

     $scope.selectChange= function() {
        // Reset AccountName if AccountStatus=='Terminated'
        if($scope.account.AccountStatus=='Terminated')
             $scope.account.AccountName = '';      
     };
   }]);
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
<select ng-model="account.AccountStatus" 
   ng-change="resetAccountName(account.AccountStatus == 'Terminated')">
     .......
     options goes here
     .......
</select>
```

then in your controller create the function resetAccountName like this

```
 $scope.resetAccountName = function(flag){
   if(flag == true){
      $scope.account.AccountName = "";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the AccountStatus variable to a function that clears the AccountName variable, e.g. in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('AccountStatus', function(status) {
    if (status == 'Terminated')
        $scope.AccountName = null;
})
```